# grep + match value only if value in the end of line

Tags: linux, solaris, perl, grep, awk

please advice what is wrong with my code, ( I run this code on both OS linux and solaris )

I don't get the line from:

```
    "file ended with .tmp"
```

example:

I need to verify if $FILE ended with **.tmp** or **.old** etc ...

code with the following example set the parameter: FILE=hosts.tmp

so I expected that grep will match the **".tmp**" and because **.tmp** is the last characters

- the same for other TOKENS as ",TEMP" or "previos" or "-OLD" ...etc

code ( ksh script )

```
     TOKENS=".tmp .old .previous -log temp ,TEMP -OLD previos"

     FILE=hosts.tmp

      for TOKEN in ` echo $TOKENS `

        do

        [[ ` echo $FILE  | grep -c '$TOKEN$'  ` -eq 1 ]] && echo "file ended with $TOKEN"

        done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with your code:

1) as the TOKEN gets passed to grep you need to escape the `-` like this:

```
TOKENS=".tmp .old .previous \-log temp ,TEMP"
```

2) you are using single quotes which means variables are not being expanded, replace with quotes:

```
[[ ` echo $FILE  | grep -c "$TOKEN$"  ` -eq 1 ]] && echo file ended with $TOKEN
```

Comment: I already set "$TOKEN$" in my code - its also not match the ".tmp"

Comment: I just took your code made my modifications and ran it on a Linux box, output was: `file ended with .tmp`

Comment: then you are using different code than the one you posted here. In the one you posted there is no trailing space.

Comment: Use `grep -c -- "$TOKEN$"` and you won't need to escape the hyphen.